# xcom value are overwritten by else statement in if/else loop

Tags: airflow

I'm looping through a folder with some sql files. For each file I want to push them as xcom value with specific value for each queries.

The code below is kind of working however not when adding else statement. `not set` value is overwriting everything.

```
directory = r'airflow_home/dags/sql'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as file:
        sqlFile = file.read()
        file.close()
        if filename == 'api_params.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(partitioned_key,execution_date_second,partitioned_key,next_execution_date_second)
        if filename == 'create_fact_table.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(fact_table_dest)
        if filename == 'create_geo_table.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(fact_table_dest)
        if filename == f'{geo_type}'+'.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(execution_date)
            filename = 'geo_query'
        if filename == 'schema_' + f'{schema}' + '.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(fact_table_dest,raw_table_dest,execution_date,next_execution_date)
            filename = 'production_query'
        if filename == 'insert_key.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(raw_table_dest,execution_date,next_execution_date)
        else:
            query = 'not set'
        task_instance.xcom_push(key=filename, value=query)
```

can someone explain me what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiple `if` statements, which are executed one after the other. The `else` just referring to the last if statement and therefore overwriting previous set `query` parameter. What you are actually looking for is `elif` - see [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

```
directory = r'airflow_home/dags/sql'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as file:
        sqlFile = file.read()
        file.close()
        if filename == 'api_params.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(partitioned_key,execution_date_second,partitioned_key,next_execution_date_second)
        elif filename == 'create_fact_table.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(fact_table_dest)
        elif filename == 'create_geo_table.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(fact_table_dest)
        elif filename == f'{geo_type}'+'.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(execution_date)
            filename = 'geo_query'
        elif filename == 'schema_' + f'{schema}' + '.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(fact_table_dest,raw_table_dest,execution_date,next_execution_date)
            filename = 'production_query'
        elif filename == 'insert_key.sql':
            query = sqlFile.format(raw_table_dest,execution_date,next_execution_date)
        else:
            query = 'not set'
        task_instance.xcom_push(key=filename, value=query)
```